# Laptop with AMD desktop processor and RTX 2080 or better

Tags: laptop

I have become convinced that the recent top AMD processors are better than Intel for most purposes, so I have started looking for a laptop with an AMD desktop processor and discrete graphics.
There are a few laptops with AMD desktop processors that are available right now. However, for reasons of power or cooling, they only seem to go up to NVIDIA RTX 2080 graphics. My current laptop has a 2080 and a 9900k, so it is clearly possible to achieve this (with some sacrifices in  noise and heat, it must be said).

Another disadvantage is the lack of 4k screen options. In these times, when even flagship smartphones can have 4K screens packed into a screen space an eight of the size, a 1080p screen on a high-end laptop, even if it has a high refresh rate, is not really good enough. The lack of Thunderbolt 3 on a lot of these models is also a downside.

Are there any computers that currently have all or most of these characteristics?